# Storing data from a wav file into an array

Tags: c++11, wav

I am trying to store the data of a wav file in an array of ints so far this is what I have

```
    int BufferSize = 4096;//CW.NumSampels;
    int* buffer = new int[BufferSize];
    FILE InFile = fopen(pParent->m_StrWavFileName, "r");
    size_t bytesRead = fread(&Riff, 1, sizeof(RiffWav), InFile);
```

Does this store all the data of a wav file into the buffer array of size 4096?

Comment: Probably the non-binary opening gets in the way.

Comment: `buffer` is allocated but not actually used in any way. So no, whatever that code does, it doesn't store any data in `buffer`.